What arguments are missing in this g++ call?
I must use g++ to compile a program that I did not write. The repo provides an installation script that includes compilation. But I think there's a mistake in the script, as I get two "missing argument" errors. I have zero experience in C++ and with compilers, so I cannot figure out what the problem is here.
Edit: here's the complete command:
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,bridge.so -o bridge.so bridge.o bme.o bNNI.o graph.o heap.o SPR.o traverse.o utils.o initialiser.o fastme.o -fopenmp -lm -lpthread

Character at Line:1 : 16
+ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,bridge.so -o bridge.so bridge.o bme.o bNNI.o  ...
+                ~
Missing argument in parameters list.
Character at Line:1 : 24
+ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,bridge.so -o bridge.so bridge.o bme.o bNNI.o  ...
+                        ~
Missing argument in parameters list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

(This is translated from French, but it should be accurate)
I'm guessing something should come after -Wl and -soname, but I have no idea what these do.
I was hoping that, by chance, this would be a trivial problem for someone with experience with this compiler.
I looked at the manual of gcc, but I don't understand the lingo in there.
I also contacted the author of the repo, without success.

Can you provide the full command that you entered, verbatim ?

@HenriDehaybe You should [edit] your question and add it there :) (But anyway I don't see the mistake here)

Are you trying to build a Linux library on Windows? What is the repo in question? Which g++ are you using?

@molbdnilo This one: https://github.com/andygaspar/PHYLOES. I installed mingw, the latest (14 I think, I can't check today, I'm not on the correct machine). You can find the script in installation.sh. It's the second g++ call that fails, the first one worked. Specifically, I followed this tutorial to get g++ : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

It's a sh (Bourne shell) script, but it seems like you're trying to execute it as a PowerShell script. Use the mingw shell, and sh installation.sh.

@molbdnilo I did that and it worked. Thanks you.
